# Correct register for offset 0x54 on ICH4M chipset to force fast write speeds on primary slave

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, pata, chipset

I've read this: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/hp-2510p-owners-lounge.352887/page-28#post5519419

I'm looking for the same but I have ICH4M not ICH8M.

There is 1011 by default.

This is limiting my SSD drive to 99 MB/s read and only 24 MB/s write.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are incorrectly detecting a 40-pin cable?

Comment: Yes. It's shows such message when booting Linux.

Comment: Also take a look at my read speed. I need to force the drive to work in UDMA6 mode in hdparm. This is A-Data S396 30 GB drive in SATA to PATA caddy.